# Corresponding CMakeList for a Qt pro file 

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I need to convert Qt Project to CMake , as i want to integrate it with other projects which are already in CMake .

The Qt .Pro file is as follows ,

```
TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += ./lib

# Input

HEADERS +=  dollar/GestureTemplate.h \
    dollar/PathWriter.h \
    dollar/GeometricRecognizerTypes.h \
    dollar/GeometricRecognizer.h \
    dollar/SampleGestures.h \
    lib/GestureTemplate.h \
    lib/PathWriter.h \
    lib/GeometricRecognizerTypes.h \
    lib/GeometricRecognizer.h \
    lib/SampleGestures.h \
    lib/MultiStrokeGestureTemplate .h \
    lib/MultiStrokeGestureTemplate .h \
    lib/MultiStrokeGestureTemplate .h \
    lib/MultiStrokeGestureTemplate .h \
    lib/SampleMultiStrokeGestures.h \
    lib/MultipleStrokeGestureTemplate.h \
    lib/utils.h
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    lib/GeometricRecognizer.cpp

LIBS += -L/usr/lib \
    -lml \
```

There is only one directory Lib and in the main path there is main.cpp , all the other files are inside Lib directory .

I don't know much about cmake i have come up with the following cmake list for the above qt project.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
Project(dollar)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("lib")
# Make Executable
ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.cpp)
# Link the executable to the Hello library.
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main -lml -L/usr/lib)
```

cmake succeeds but after that make gives me many errors ,see the error log -> http://www.text-upload.com/read,4022366863337 .What all additions i require to make in CMake List ?.

Comment: I think your TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES is wrong. I do not use gcc but with Visual Studio I just specify the names of the libraries on that line and CMake generates the proper link flags to my linker from that.

Comment: It seems to be working fine(in linux) after making changes suggested by @Greg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have missed lib/GeometricRecognizer.cpp file

```
# Make Executable
ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.cpp lib/GeometricRecognizer.cpp)
```